# Generic attack on Hmac sha256

Tags: hash, hmac, sha-256, attack, side-channel-attack

Is there any generic attack on HMAC SHA 256 ?

I am currently reading up on attacks on Hmac sha-256. However most of the papers I've found are about side channel attacks such as Differential power Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no known practical generic attacks on HMAC-SHA256. Brute-force attacks are generic, but are not practical.

Comment: The closest to a practical attack on HMAC-SHA-256 is that it is easy to exhibit pairs of equivalent keys (just make one the SHA-256 of the more-than-64-byte other). Equivalent keys are _not_ usually considered an attack on a MAC.